# Update QTY checkout cart Magento not working after update to 1.9.2.4

Tags: checkout, cart

In 2014 I've added some code to auto update the product qty in the cart checkout of Magento so if I were to change the qty of the product it automatically updates this. Sometimes a customer forgets to press enter or click on update shoppingcart. This worked very well.

I've placed this code in the head.phmtl file of my template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxCartPost(item){
    element='cart[' + item +'][qty]';
    qty=document.getElementById(element).value;
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/ajaxcart')?>',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: jQuery("form#cartform").serializeArray(), 
        type:'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.status == 'Y'){
                jQuery('.cart').replaceWith(data.cart);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

And disabled this line in /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

```
<input name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" size="4" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12" />
```

with

```
<input name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" id="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" size="4" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" maxlength="12" style="float: left; width:1.9em!important;" onkeyup="ajaxCartPost(<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>);"  />
```

I've updated the Magento shop from version 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.2.4 and all of a sudden this doesn't work anymore. I did some tracing to check and see if there was an error but there is none. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Br,

Steve

Comment: Maybe you lost the formKey. Please, add it to the form and maybe works. Content related: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12637/magento-quantity-in-checkout-shopping-cart-doesnt-work-properly